# Control reset event in angular

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm writing my own component and want to do custom reset (I need to cleanup some labels and etc.)

So, when somebody call `this.form.reset();` I want to respond to this event and make some cleanup actions.

I don't want to ask developer to send custom reset for my component like 
`this.form.reset({myControl: null})`

I just want to react on form reset. Could you help me? How I can do it?
I use ReactiveAngular Forms

Example:

```
<form ...>
  <my-own-component formControlName="fieldName"></my-own-component>
</form>
```

Comment: What kind of *cleanup actions* do you need to do?

Answer (score 6):

Subscribe on status changes of the form and on next tick check the pristine status if it is true - form was reset.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.formGroup.statusChanges.subscribe(x => {
     setTimeout(()=>console.log(this.formGroup.pristine),0);
   });
}
```